# Order in a list of adjectives

Tags: adjectives

Is this the correct order in a list of adjectives in a sentence?:

1.Quantity or number

2.Quality or opinion

3.Size

4.Age

5.Shape

6.Color

7.Proper adjective (often nationality, other place of origin, or material)

8.Purpose or qualifier

Example: I have 1 cheap little old white american sleeping mattress.

Is it the same thing if we use *adjectival nouns*(nouns which occupy the function of an adjective when there are 2 nouns in a row)?. Here are some examples:

> a race horse is a horse that runs in races
>   a horse race is a race for horses
>   a boat race is a race for boats 
>   a love story is a story about love
>   a war story is a story about war
>   a tennis ball is a ball for playing tennis
>   tennis shoes are shoes for playing tennis 
>   a computer exhibition is an exhibition of computers

Comment: *I have an old mattress* gets the same point across in most American contexts. But  anyway, your question is sure to be a duplicate of one already asked here on this topic.

Comment: The first question concerning adjectives order is solved but my second question about adjectival nouns not.

Comment: Can you give an example or two of your second question?

Comment: Examples:      •a race horse is a horse that runs in races
•a horse race is a race for horses
•a boat race is a race for boats
•a love story is a story about love
•a war story is a story about war
•a tennis ball is a ball for playing tennis
•tennis shoes are shoes for playing tennis
•a computer exhibition is an exhibition of computers

Comment: @ Juan, I have edited your question to add your examples to your question, as you should have done. I think that these examples adequately demonstrate the idea:  if you are talking about an X kind of Y, the word order must be "an X Y". If you want to add some adjectives to describe your X Y, they must all be placed in front of X Y in the same order as they would before any other noun.

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what your second question is asking. Those sentences are all correct...?

Comment: relaxing: The main function of an adjective is to describe a noun. When we have a noun after another noun is necessary to become the first one into an adjective . You can prove this matter because an adjective always places in front of the noun that describes.